# Backup files and MBR of windows partition without cloning whole image

Tags: windows, boot, partitioning, backup

I have a new computer with Windows pre-installed. I will re-partition the hard drive, keeping the original Windows installation (on a now-smaller partition) and dual-boot Linux. I will install programs and keep user data on separate partitions. Something like this:

- sda1 - Windows (OS only)
- sda2 - Windows applications
- sda3 - Linux
- sda4 - User data files (nothing executable)

The premise is that if Windows gets riddled with viruses I can restore sda1 to its initial state and wipe sda2.

I wish to take a snapshot of the Windows installation on sda1. I could `dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/home/me/sda1.img` and I believe that would be sufficient to back up the files as well as the MBR, and that the reverse `dd` would correctly restore me to the initial (bootable) state.

However, sda1 may be "big" (say, 200GB) of which only a "small" part is used by the original installation. So maybe I could

```
mount /dev/sda1 /windows
tar -cf /home/me/windows.tar /windows
dd if=/dev/sda1 bs=512 count=1 /home/me/windows_mbr.img
```

To restore this, I imagine I would wipe and reformat sda1, reverse the `dd` and unpack the tar.

Would this correctly restore Windows to its original (bootable) state?

Is this compatible with dual booting (e.g. with grub)?

If not, what else do I need to do?

Comment: Why not use a real imaging backup software? Those software can even create an image from a running instance of Windows. Using tar for backup Windows files is useless as all the NTFS security information are lost thus restoring such a backup is impossible. Also all the reparse points (soft-/hard links) and alternate NTFS streams are lost.

Answer (score 1):

No – it would destroy nearly all metadata that NTFS holds about the file. Most importantly, it'd lose file permissions (ACLs), but it'd also mishandle reparse points (which are more than just symlinks), alternate streams (which are like xattrs), and so on.

(Imagine copying your Linux system to a FAT32 drive. Some files were owned by root, others by special accounts; some were executable or even setuid; FAT32 would lose all that information.)

If you want to make a file-level backup from within Linux, use `wimcapture` from wimlib (this is equivalent to [the official DISM imaging tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/capture-and-apply-windows-using-a-single-wim) that comes with Windows) and make sure to point it at a raw disk device, so that it could use libntfs-3g to read most of the metadata into a WIM-format archive:

```
wimcapture /dev/sda1 windows.wim
wimapply windows.wim /dev/sda1
```

I don't have a 100% guarantee of this working – you might get better results from actual `dism /capture-image`, which you can run from any Windows installer USB stick.

```
dism /capture-image /imagefile:D:\windows.wim /capturedir:C:\
dism /apply-image /imagefile:D:\windows.wim /applydir:C:\
```

However, there's a simpler method which is to make a *block-level* backup and only skip the unallocated areas – this can be done using ntfsclone:

```
ntfsclone -o windows.img /dev/sda1
```

This will create a *sparse file*, which only occupies as much space as it contains data, even though on the outside it looks much larger. You can archive it but make sure to use `tar --sparse`. Special tools aren't needed to restore this image, just `cp` or `dd` it back to the partition.

Since ntfsclone copies data at block level, it is guaranteed to work with any Windows version; it only needs to understand the NTFS "allocation bitmap" (which does not change).

Finally, two things about the MBR:

First, it isn't very useful to back up the "boot code" part of the MBR. It contains *very* generic code and there are tools both on Windows (bootsect.exe) and Linux (ms-sys) which can write a fresh boot code on demand. (Unless you've overwritten it with GRUB already, in which case you can just use grub-install.)

The only useful part you're backing up is the partition table. But you should be using 'sfdisk' to back up the partition table instead making a raw sector copy.

```
sfdisk --dump /dev/sda > partitions.txt
sfdisk /dev/sda < partitions.txt
```

Second, new Windows computers *do not use* the MBR for their boot process. On UEFI-based PCs, the entirety of the bootloader lives in the "EFI System Partition", and the partition table is no longer at sector 0 – it lives at sectors 1–64. (Using sfdisk will correctly capture both the MBR and UEFI/GPT partition table formats.)

Answer (score 0):

You just need a decent imaging software that copies only blocks in use.

`partclone` is my tool of choice for imaging. It's Linux-based and available for example in Ubuntu's repositories. It's also built-in into [GRML](https://grml.org)'s full release.

For file-level backup on Windows I'm using [Veeam Agent](https://www.veeam.com/en/windows-endpoint-server-backup-free.html). It's based on Windows's shadow copy mechanism. It can restore an unbootable system using a recovery media, but it has to be built for a particular system - there's no generic recovery media image.

One thing that you have to consider in your scheme is that installed programs have their entries in the Windows registry, which would be lost when restoring.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to backup the Windows partition using tools that are
Windows-oriented, that are best installed in and launched from Windows.

There are several such utilities, where my favorite is
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html).

Such software will backup the entire partition, but only backup sectors
that are used. The backup data can also be compressed, therefore
resulting in an even smaller backup file.

If ever the size of the Windows
partition is changed, the tool can restore to a different-sized partition.

A boot media can also be generated, for cases where Windows becomes
unbootable, for example after a nasty virus attack.